# "they might not be as well prepared" or "they might as well not be prepared"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, adjectives, phrases

The context of the conversation is about auditing classes at a university...

> Woman: Because anyone who is taking the class for a grade,  **for credit**, puts in a lot of time preparing for it, doing the reading and assignments; whereas people who aren't, **they might not be as well prepared**. And that would have affected the quality of class discussion.

My question is as follows...

Does she intend to express that **they might not be as well prepared** *as people who take the class for a grade*.

or

The expression that **they might not be as well prepared** is the same as *they might as well not be prepared*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means:

"Does she intend to express that they might not be as well prepared *as people who take the class for a grade*."

In this context she is using 'credit' as an uncountable noun.

In the same sense as "If she did most of the work she should get the credit".

Comment: Is it like ellipsis in linguistics? I mean dropping second **as** and the rest of words.

Comment: Yes. It would be pointless to repeat, and would slow readers down, and could even momentarily confuse them.

Comment: You also answer my question to "Why does she say for credit instead of for a credit or for credits"?" Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up several different meanings of **as well**.

**Might as well** means something like *essentially* or "doesn't make any difference"; if you say "I might *as well* not even study" it means that it makes no difference if you study.

The other is using **as** as a comparative (like "this book is just *as* good as yours") and **well** as an adverb meaning *good* or *satisfactory*.

In your example sentence, when the woman says "...might not be *as well* prepared" she means "might not be prepared *as satisfactorily* (as people who do the work)".

You can tell the difference in meaning by where *as well* is used in the sentence and whether it's next to *might* or whether it's next to an adjective or participle.

- might *as well* not be prepared: phrase meaning "essentially"
- might not be prepared *as well*: comparative

Reference: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-well-as

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was a bit confused by where **as well** is used. Just too similar to tell.

Answer (score 1):

(1) She says that *people who aren't* (taking the class for a grade) may not be *as well prepared* as those who are.

It definitely doesn't mean the same as *They might as well not be prepared*, which would mean that being prepared makes no difference. (Not being prepared would probably be as good as being prepared.)

(2) I don't know.